# C#.NET change text of textbox

Tags: c#, .net, events, textbox, event-handling

How do we call a form1 class event from another class present in form1.cs?

```
public partial class form1 : form
{
// an event to change the text of a textbox
}

public class A
{
sendtext()
{
//text to be sent to the texbox
// the text is created as a output of a thread
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question, correct the code and explain better what you want to achieve?

Comment: And also make it a valid C# program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an event in `A` class and subscribe to it from `form1`.

```
class A
{
   public event Action<string> TextReady;

   private OnTextReady(string text)
   {
      var ev = TextReady;
      if(ev!=null) ev(text);        
   }
}

class Form1
{
   private _a = new A();
   public Form1()
   {
      _a.TextReady+= (text)=> textBox.Text = text;
   }
}
```

You will probably stumble into cross-thread limitations, but that's another question, just write a comment if you will.

Comment: Thanks! I realise that I was quite unclear in the question, but you really helped me! I couldn't really understand if I should be trying to learn delegates or something else

Comment: Yup, it was quite a challenge to get what was the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always just change the text directly.

```
public partial class form1 : form
{
    public string TextboxText 
    {
        get { return txtBox.Text; }
        set { txtBox.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Then just do:

```
form1.TextboxText = "My new text";
```